# Python join two dataframes with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I'm trying to join two different dataframes. I'll explain what I did so far so you'll understand what I have tried. I'm kinda new to python and I'd really appreciate every hint where i can improve my code.

I've got a dataset which looks similiar to this:

```
cluster, Type
      1,    M
      1,    T
      1,    M
```

I've grouped the data and did some aggregation. In addition to this I added some columns to the dataset. So my dataframe is looking like this now:

```
>>> df
cluster, Type, M, T
      1,    M, 0, 0
      1,    T, 0, 0
      1,    M, 0, 0
```

And the aggregation looks like this:

```
>>> a
cluster  Type, len
      1,    M,   2
      1,    T,   1
```

I want to put ever *len* from a to the corresponding column in df so the result would be:

```
>>> df
cluster, Type, M, T
      1,    M, 2, 0
      1,    T, 0, 1
```

What I've tried to do is:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    c = row['cluster']
    t = row['Type']
    val = a.loc[
        (a['cluster'] == c) &
        (a['Type'] == t),
        'len'
    ]
    row[t] = val
```

In the end, it failed because the last line, *row[t]* didn't get updated. But I have the feeling I'm doing this in a very complicated way.

Any ideas how to do it in an more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. It still involves a loop, but I think it's clearer and faster than what you were trying to do. It only uses your original `df`, no need for the aggregation you provided.

Start by making a dictionary of the length per `Type`:

```
len_dict = df.groupby('Type').size().to_dict()
>>> len_dict
{'M': 2, 'T': 1}
```

Then drop the duplicates in your original `df`, finally looping through the keys in `len_dict` and assigning the approriate columns to the respective keys:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

for t in len_dict:
    df.loc[df.Type.eq(t), t] = len_dict[t]

>>> df
   cluster Type  M  T
0        1    M  2  0
1        1    T  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to go from 'a' to your expected result using `set_index`, `unstack` and `reset_index`:

```
df = a.set_index([a.Type,'cluster','Type'])['len']\
      .unstack(0).rename_axis(None,axis=1)\
      .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   cluster Type    M    T
0        1    M  2.0  NaN
1        1    T  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Hey i've tried your code i guess i didn't write it correctly *a* is a *DataFrameGroupBy' object. When i tried to use it i got `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method` and after trying the apply method i got the error `NameError: name 'set_index' is not defined`.
I'm kinda clueless what to do from there now. Because your solution is really interesting to me it's looking very good.

Comment: In your question, `a` appears to be a dataframe. created similiar to this `a = df.groupby(['cluster','Type'], as_index=False)['M'].count().rename(columns={'M':'len'})`